# IMail Distribution List

Tags: distribution-lists, email

Is it possible to setup IMail with a distribution list, i.e. sales@mydomain.com would forward to a list of sales people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.ipswitch.com/_Messaging/IMailServer/v11/Help/Admin/index.htm Look under domain administration then list administration.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an alias can do this, or use the mailing list functionality; although I think that's a little clunky and overkill for what you appear to be after.